# Wordpress Header Image not showing (404 not found)

Tags: wordpress, header, http-status-code-404

I have created some custom headers for each of my pages that change at certain breakpoints to be more legible. The file was uploaded and is in the media section, however when I use my browser to see any errors, it's saying that the image isn't found even though I've copied the image URL directly from the media page.

Here is example css of one of the header image:

```
.img-container_whymac {
min-height: 420px;
background-image: url(https://hire.mcmaster.ca/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/hire-mcmaster-summer-header.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: 1100px 450px;
background-position: center top;
border-bottom: 7px solid #f4bd56;
/*padding: 40px; (If don't want to set min-height or some image content is there) */
```

}

This is the URL to the image I'm linking to: https://hire.mcmaster.ca/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/hire-mcmaster-whymac-header.png

Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Thank you

Comment: What if you try adding double quotes: `background-image: url("https://hire.mcmaster.ca/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/hire-mcmaster-summer-header.png");`

Comment: I've tried adding quotes and the error is still there

Comment: You might have to clear your cache and hard reload after editing a .css file